# Rewriting non-linear history in Mercurial / Hg?

Tags: mercurial, rebase

I want to hide a topological head (leftover not included into merge of feature branch) without damaging history graph.

The common solution is to merge closing branch commit back to `default` but this puts extra edge to the history with the length of 10 years of history (damaging `hg glog`).

I want to rewrite the project history and to include that closing commit before the historical integration merge to `default`.

Seems https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension & https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HisteditExtension extensions operate over the linear history only, unfortunately the history above (and around) the integration merge is a bit messy.

**What way is it possible to rewrite non-linear history in Mercurial?**

Basically I want to move `C` in between `F` and `M`:

```
 *B
 |
 *M(erge)
 |\   *C(losing)
 | \ /
A*  *F(eature)
```

to make it looks like (here `C'` `M'` `B'` are only changing hashes):

```
  *B'
  |
  *M'(erge)
  /\ 
A*  *C'(losing)
    |
    *F(eature)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already pushed, so that no one else has `M` or `B`, then you can:

1. Update to `A`
2. Merge with `C`, creating `M'`  (I don't see a need for a `C'`)
3. Rebase or graft `B`, creating `B'`
4. Strip, or prune `M` and `B` -- or just ignore them as long as they are secret phase
5. Push

If things have already been pushed than you can't do anything destructive to `M` or its descendants. But steps up through #4 will be fine.

(Unless your team is using https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChangesetEvolution)

Comment: Closing should be integrated into the mainline to keep `hg log -r 'heads(all())'` small. With large number of heads remote protocol is slow.

Comment: But since C already existed, which closed the branch, my suggestion in step 2 just uses it. Its still closed.  Or maybe I am misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: Incidentally for performance I have found that using `hg serve` for the remote connections is much faster than running of just a shared drive / network folder location.

Comment: I managed to rebase the history as you suggested. There is an extra step: `hg phase --force --draft 'all()'` to mark public data as draft. Of course, I reused closing commit in the merge as you pointed in the comment. My history graph was actually a bit more complicated: at the time of the merge `M` there were several heads and `M` has merged  into the mainline. So I merge closing to the point before mainline integration and then rebased the mainline on top of the `M'` merge. I'll add illustration in own answer.

Comment: Glad it helped. I wasn't sure if you used phases or not, as they are not 'on' by default IIRC.

Comment: Evolve extension isn't "experimental" alreadu a lot of time and even bundled with THG. Must have for reducing headache: evolve+topic + non-publishing stage-server push + publishing server for prod

Comment: @LazyBadger on https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChangesetEvolution it does say "The experimental EvolveExtension adds more commands..."

Comment: See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChangesetEvolution?action=info - even in 2018 it had only cosmetic change, and **5 years** *cost a lot*. I **use** evolve somehow, I didn't find *any rakes* (!!!) in use-cases

Comment: I agree, it works well. I removed the comment in the answer referring to it as experimental

Answer (score 0):

My actual history was a bit more complicated:

```
*B
|
*M2(erge)
|\
| \
|  * E(xtra)
|  |
*X * M1(erge)
|  /\   * C(losing)
| /  \ /
|/    * U(nrelated)
* S(tart)
```

So I marked everything as `draft`:

```
hg phase --force --draft 'all()'
```

and merged closing `C` with extra `E` - the latest changeset before second merge `M2`:

```
hg checkout -C -r "E"
hg merge -r "C"
```

Resulting graph is:

```
*B
|
*M2(erge)  *Mc(losing merge)
|\   _____/\ 
| \ /       \  
|  * E(xtra) \
|  |          * C(losing)
*X * M1(erge) /
|  /\   _____/
| /  \ /
|/    * U(nrelated)
* S(tart)
```

Then the task is to replace merge `M2` and rebase history above it to the new merge `Mc`:

```
hg rebase -s M2 -d Mc
```

resulting in graph:

```
    * B'
    |
    * M2'(merge)
   /\
  /  *Mc(losing merge)
 /  / \____ 
|  /       \_  
|  * E(xtra) \
|  |          * C(losing)
*X * M1(erge) /
|  /\   _____/
| /  \ /
|/    * U(nrelated)
* S(tart)
```

At the end `M2'` and `B'` are rewritten.

**Bottomline**: `hg` allows rebasing merges if you move them forward - it is the base for complicated rewrites.

I think if the graph was more complicated the expressive power of `hg` CLI wouldn't be enough to rebase changes.